# Prefill web form with data stored in app

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiwebview

With the iPhone `UiWebView` is it possible to prefill an html form with username and other
account details that are stored in the app's data folder. Using iOS 5.1 sdk
So I would need to read the file with the customers's information stored and then prefill the web form from the `UIWebView`. I need to know if this can be done and if so any tutorials how to do it would be useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could read the data from your app's bundle then run a JavaScript function that takes the data as parameters and uses it to pre-populate the form.

You can execute the Javascript in your UIWebView by using the method

```
stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
```

I'm not a JavaScript expert so I don't want to comment on the best way to write the JavaScript function to pre-populate the form but I know its possible.